Let's get critical: Jul 2013 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love LEGO® Answers, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 6 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Part of the problem is that, due to its use of the plain-jane Area 51 banner, instead of something fun and LEGO-y, the initial impression might be that this is a scam site which steals answers from other places.

Final Results

Power Functions battery box and receiver limits
Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

How is the LEGO plastic different from Megablok plastic?
Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

Damage Boiling LEGO Bricks
Net Score: 5 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

How many standard 2x4 LEGO elements are produced in a single 2x4 mold injection?
Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

What is the purpose of the hole in the 12 x 12 boat bow (6051)?
Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

How should I connect two LEGO cylinders with pistons to measure the movement caused by sea waves?
Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)



I love this site, but it's too niche.  It is almost like having a StackExchange site solely for, I don't know, Spring Framework. 
I toss "LEGO help" and "LEGO Discussion" into Google and Bricks is on page two.
I think it needs to allow expansion into all things LEGO and not restrain itself to building, and the existing base should try to generate questions on their own that might attract visitors. I posted at least one idea in the "Is LEGOland off-topic" meta question, suggesting we allow questions regarding LEGOLand, LEGO Discovery Centers and LEGO Stores.
Also, that LEGO movie is coming out and we are going to get some hits due to it, so I highly recommend getting prepared to handle that.
